# Series of Linear Equations From Outputs of $u(x,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have problem where I am trying to work backwards and my grasp on the concepts of PDE, DE, and system of linear equations is lacking. I have three variables $x$, $y$, $z$ which are all related.

Given $u(x,y)$

$u(1, 1)$ gives the form $${z(t) = 2(t - 1)^2}$$
$u(1, 43)$ gives the form $${z(t) = 2(t - 1)^2 + 21}$$ and
$u(6, 3)$ gives the form $${z(t) = 3(t - 5/2)^2 - 11/4}$$

Its apparently obvious to me that this is a series of linear equations of which I can get the super position of so I can plug in $u(y,z)$ and get the equation of $x(t)$. My question is how do I work backwards from these outputs.

Comment: I do not believe it is clear what this question has to do with PDEs or ODEs. Is $u(x,y)$ assumed to solve some PDE in $x, y$?

Comment: I was just aware that PDEs and ODEs have a super position concept and the data I am formulating this out of seems to have similar forms to the concept. If you don't believe it is relevant please feel free to suggest better tags

Comment: Okay. Then yes i'd suggest systems-of-equations maybe or some algebra related tag. This is currently framed as an algebraic question. Few other suggestions that may improve the question. (1) it isn't clear what role $z$ plays. Is $z = u(x,y)$? (2) is $u(y,z)$ a typo? Seems to make more sense that you take the expression for $u(x,y)$ and solve for x in terms of $y$ and $z.$ This depends on your answer to (1) of course. (3) What class of functions (polynomial, continuous, smooth) are you assuming or are there no restrictions? These should precisely frame your question.